# How do you publish an application you've made in Android Studio to Google Play?

Tags: android, android-studio

I can see where you can publish on GitHub, but not to Google Play, and I can't see how to publish anything to it.

Comment: Check this article https://themanifest.com/development/how-publish-app-google-play-step-step-guide

Comment: Be careful. "Publishing" to GitHub is basically setting up a repository for your code on Github and if you are not careful you might create a public repo and share all your code with the world. As of publishing to google play store is not a one click process https://developer.android.com/studio/test